# Create a layer with black transparent over an activity

Tags: android

I want to create a layer with transparent layer over an activity and I need to make visible only a particular view, say for an example "Login Button". It something mean that making hole on layer exactly the size of the button. Please anyone help me out of this.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: [Sample image] (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3yZokwUGKFgNEdpSnlYSUJOUGM/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programatically, you can use Canvas to create a layer. Fill the whole thing with your color and cut out a hole.

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Paint transparentPaint = new Paint;
    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //first fill everything with your covering color
        paint.setColor(yourTransparentColor);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);
        //now clear out the area you want to see through
        transparentPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
        transparentPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        Rect rect=new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);//make this your rect!
        canvas.drawRect(rect,transparentPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi HalR, Thanks for your answer. Its working but cutted rect is looks  black color, I need to make visible the button which is on the activity layout on the cut out area. So now the view looks like, button is placed on the transparent layer.

Comment: Can you see the button?  Or is it covered with black?

Comment: Nop, it coverd with black.

Comment: I believe you need to add transparentPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);  (See my edit)

Comment: I tried this also and the cutout area is pitch black :(

Comment: Did you set the  transparentPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);  ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly

Your parent Layout of the `Activity` will be a `RelativeLayout`. In your parent layout at the bottom add another child RelativeLayout that implments the `match_parent` parameters for both width and height. You can then set a color like this `#99000000` to it's background. This will give you a black transparent layer over your parent.

Something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <!-- here you add your activities views ect... -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/childLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#99000000">
        <!-- This will be your overlay so here you can add your login button ect -->
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I didn't test this but it should solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

On following "HalR" Steps , I was able to achieve the transparent background Thanks to him and found some of you are getting pitch black on the cut made over transparent layer is due to Graphic rendering . that can be enabled using below code inside onDraw method

```
` @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
     .....
     ..... // your draw rect creation and other stuff `
```

which will let you have the transparent area by eliminating the Pitch black color

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question then this is what you wanted:
You tried to overlay a transparent view on your activity and cut out holes to see few stuffs.

here i found an useful example which shows how can you cut out bitmaps and combine them. i would suggest for your problem just take the part of cutting the bitmap and remember to set the imageview backgroung with opacity as shown here

> android:background="#00ffffff"

here is the layout i created

> 

```
    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>"

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" >
    </ImageView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my maniactivity

> public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    Bitmap foreground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.android_cat_wanted);
    foreground = punchAHoleInABitmap(foreground);
    iv.setImageBitmap(foreground);
}

private Bitmap punchAHoleInABitmap(Bitmap foreground) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(foreground.getWidth(), foreground.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(foreground, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    float radius = (float)(getScreenSize().x *.35);
    float x = (float) ((getScreenSize().x*.5));
    float y = (float)  ((getScreenSize().y*.5));
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
    return bitmap;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private Point getScreenSize() {
    WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
    Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size;
}
```

}

hope you find it useful

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/punch-a-hole-in-a-bitmap-by-using-androids-porter-duff-xfer/

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/punch-a-hole-in-a-bitmap-by-using-androids-porter-duff-xfer/ 

i forgot to share this link please follow this, it was helpful for deriving the answer